# appendChild() not working in forEach() method even though the element is a DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

I have the following function: -

```
function processResult(responses) {
        for (i = 0; i < responses.length - 1; i++) {
            row = document.createElement("tr")
            naam = document.createElement("td")
            ema = document.createElement("td")
            tit = document.createElement("td")
            content = document.createElement("td")
            status = document.createElement("td")
            content.classList.add("text-justify")
            var containeris = [naam, tit, content, status];
            naam.innerHTML = responses[i][1].split(" ")[0]
            tit.innerHTML = responses[i][6]
            status.innerHTML = responses[i][11]
            str = "<a href = 'javascript:trigger(" + i + ")'>[Read More]</a>"
            content.innerHTML = responses[i][7].slice(0, 50) + "..." + str
            containeris.forEach(function (el) {
                row.appendChild(el);
            });
            document.getElementById("mytable").appendChild(row)

        }



    }
        function trigger(i) {
            alert(rr[i][7])
        }
```

`status.appendChild(tc)` keeps giving the following error : -

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': -
parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' at "row.appendChild(el);"
```

naam, tit, content in the array 'containeris' work fine, but as soon as I add 'status', I keep getting the above error.
The issue is, status is a DOM `<td>`
`responses` is an array containing multiple arrays which are of length 11
`responses[i][11]` is always a string
`rr` is a global array
Please help me with this issue :)

Comment: This is usually because status is not an element, but it certainly looks like one from the code. Can you console.log(status) and see what it is? you can also add a debugger; statement or breakpoint in Chrome and step through to see what it is too.

Comment: Your loop looks weird - are you intentionally skipping the last item? You have < length-1

Comment: "[object HTMLTableCellElement]" - Status
but while appending, it doesn't take it as a DOM,
Yes I have intentionally skipped the last element

Comment: I have made a few edits (in the code above) and simplified it, soon as I remove status from the array, everything works, but I need status in the array too :/

Comment: I think your issue is global vars - i just debugged your code with some hacky array data and it is fine - but I was forced to declare all vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You better change variable name from `status` to something different as `window.status` is reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)

Example

```js
status = document.createElement("div")

console.log(typeof status);
```

--Edit

Working example

```js
function processResult(responses) {
  for (i = 0; i < responses.length ; i++) {
    row = document.createElement("tr")
    naam = document.createElement("td")
    ema = document.createElement("td")
    tit = document.createElement("td")
    content = document.createElement("td")
    status1 = document.createElement("td")
    content.classList.add("text-justify")
    var containeris = [naam, tit, content, status1];
    naam.innerHTML = responses[i][1].split(" ")[0]
    tit.innerHTML = responses[i][6]
    status1.innerHTML = responses[i][11]
    str = "<a href = 'javascript:trigger(" + i + ")'>[Read More]</a>"
    content.innerHTML = responses[i][7].slice(0, 50) + "..." + str
    containeris.forEach(function(el) {
      row.appendChild(el);
    });
    document.getElementById("mytable").appendChild(row)

  }
}

processResult([
  Array(12).fill('Test')
])
```

```css
#mytable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Comment: Turns out, this is correct, status is a global variable, and changing the name worked

Answer (score 0):

I think if you declare all variables in your loop (var row = document...) (or let/const if your flavour permits)

I did debug the code, and i was forced to declare all variables, and it seemed to work fine (no js errors on the line you mention)

```js
processResult([
            [
                'abc',
                'def',
                'ghi',
                'jkl',
                'mno',
                'pqr',
                'stu',
                'vwx',
                'yz1',
                '234',
                '567',
                '890',
            ],
        ]);

function processResult(responses) {
    debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var naam = document.createElement('td');
        //var ema = document.createElement('td');
        var tit = document.createElement('td');
        var content = document.createElement('td');
        var status = document.createElement('td');
        content.classList.add('text-justify');
        var containeris = [naam, tit, content, status];
        naam.innerHTML = responses[i][1].split(' ')[0];
        tit.innerHTML = responses[i][6];
        var tc = document.createElement('span');
        tc.textContent = responses[i][11];
        status.appendChild(tc);
        var str = "<a href = 'javascript:trigger(" + i + ")'>[Read More]</a>";
        content.innerHTML = responses[i][7].slice(0, 50) + '...' + str;
        containeris.forEach(function(el) {
            row.appendChild(el);
        });
        document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer, the issue arrised as status is already a built in name and dorced declaration of variables changed their namespace to local, hence solving the issue :)